# YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Forcefully created overlay

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have a activity with multiple fragments in which i am creating youtube fragment dynamically (only when needed). When played it shows the progress bar for 10 sec and then resumes the video .Also the youtube player controls are acting weird with the warning of:
YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Forcefully created overlay:xup@fdf30e6 helper:Lazy@ad21627 view:null status: ...... {...}

Any solution?

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Any solution for this